# Typo3 - Unknown database type timestamp requested - SqlServer2012

Tags: sql-server, doctrine, timestamp, typo3

When I want to install for instance fe_login, extension_manager responds with an exception 'Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
Unknown database type timestamp requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SQLServer2012Platform may not support it. 
'

But SQL-Server does support timestamp. How can I correctly add the mapping, as described here?

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html

TYPO3 8.7.9

Comment: The SQL Server `timestamp` data type is not related to date or time, but is instead a binary value used for optimistic concurrency checking. For temporal value with date and time, consider `datetime2`.

Comment: @DanGuzman: Your comment should be written as an answer. You should may extend it a bit, but it could be an accepted answer.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you file a bug report in the TYPO3 bug tracker?

Comment: it is already there https://forge.typo3.org/issues/83779